# Does there exist any integer $ n> 1$ for which $6^{2n}-25$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

I got this question on a test and I am really curious hoe you would approach it. I tried to prove stuff using the congruence laws but I didn't manage to prove anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$N=6^{2n}-25=(6^n-5)(6^n+5)$$
none of these factors equal $1$(unless for $n=1$), Therefore $N$ is always composite.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You are looking at a difference of squares.